# Big gif from a third party site does not show in the README.md of github?

Tags: github, readme

I want to show a gif in a README.md of github.
And it works fine when the target gif is small with:

```
<img src="targetGifUrl" width="400">
```

but when the gif is big, it is not showing as expected, take this [gif](https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/612938/screenshots/2738907/800x600.gif) as an example. When I add it into README.md, it just shows:

[image]

and after clicking, it shows a website with the tip

> Content length exceeded

As the gif is from a third site, I can not change its size.

So, is it possible to show this big gif ***without saving*** and resizing it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks like [someone else](https://github.com/Commit451/ElasticDragDismissLayout/issues/6) had this issue before,

> When I open this link in Firefox, I only get the text "Content length exceeded".

and [here](https://github.com/Commit451/ElasticDragDismissLayout/commit/9cf4a5d71acbb2523a6ecd9eddd3a03f21c34f82) is the commit that fixed it.

> Add gif locally
>
> `-![Sample Gif](http://i.imgur.com/______.gif)`
>
> `+<img src="/art/sample.gif?raw=true" width="200px">`

Looks like all you have to do is save the gif and put it in your repository, no need to resize it, just link to the version in your repository. Notice how the width is specified and `raw=true` is an included parameter.

Comment: if the gif is big, 5m for example, I do not want to put a file like that big into my repository if there is another way.

Comment: @AssIstne you could always host a smaller, resized version on imgur. I'll see if I can think of anything better though

Answer (score 1):

Put Gif files in the local directory on your git repo. Then call it in readme file.

For example, If you just created a folder called demo in the root directory and put demo.gif inside it. Then you can call that in your readme file like this.

```
![Demo File](https://github.com/username/repo-name/blob/master/demo/demo.gif)
```

Eg:

```
![Screenshot](https://github.com/codemaker2015/React-native-map-view/blob/master/demo/demo.gif)
```